# button in uview in uistackview doesnt respond - ios

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 elements in stackview.

-One is email - TextField,

-Other is password - Textfield;

-the last one is UIView and it has button in it.

When I run it, the button in that view doesnt respond, while the same view out of the stackview responds normally. ALSO when i put a button in that stackview, it acts but when it is in a view in stackview it doesnt.

[image]
I am missing something but what ?
thanks

Comment: did you set the constraints because stack view also need some constraints

Comment: @V_rohit yes the problem was constraints. but not just stackview constraints also the view that contains the button need constraints. that was the missing ones. thanks for your advice. if you write down an answer ı would love to pick as an correct answer

Comment: If this is your demo project then upload it on GitHub i will check there

Comment: The red sign already showing you r missing constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey the problem is undefined constraints. Here I just created a simple solution to help you out. It is not perfect but it will helpful
When you are using stack view you need to keep few things in mind. There are two types of `stackView` horizontal and vertical `stackView` and `stackView` has some properties like

**Axis**  - means you wan it horizontal or vertical

**Alignment** - It is simple you can understand when you see, fill leading centre and training

**Distribution** -  In my thinking it is most important part of stack view

- Fill will leave three of them their natural size, and make the fourth one take up the most space. It uses Auto Layout's content hugging priority to decide which one to stretch.
- Fill Equally will make each subview the same size so they fill all the space available to the stack view.
- Fill Proportionally uses the intrinsic content size of each subview to resize them by an equal amount. So view 1 was designed to have twice as much height as views 2, 3 and 4, that ratio will remain when they are resized – all the subviews get proportionally bigger or smaller.
- Equal Spacing does not resize the subviews, and instead resizes the spacing between the subviews to fill the space.
- Equal Centering is the most complicated, but for many people also the most aesthetically pleasing. It attempts to ensure the centers of each subview are equally spaced. This might mean that the right edge of view 1 is only 10 points from the left edge of view 2, while the right edge of view 2 is 50 points from the left edge of view 3, but what matters is that the centers of view 1, 2, 3 and 4 are all identically spaced.

**Spacing** - spacing is used to provide the space between objects like label,  button etc.

[image][image]

I set the spacing between items 15 and distribution fill equally so they can fill the space available to the `stack view`.

here is the link to project https://github.com/waytorohit/SOreadytohelp so you can better understand.

References - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/31/2/uistackview-by-example

Comment: Thanks to you, here is my find out. the stackview doesnt function right, if you dont define constraints for both stackview and the uiviews that are placed in that stackview. Every element in that views(in stackview) should be right. there shouldnt be any ambiguous height/width/x/y . otherwise stackview behave ubnormally. thank you for your help

Comment: yes it is behave sometimes very abnormally haha ;) . Thanks happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to give constraints
2. first delete view and button in your stack view and re-add then
   create a viewController and of this viewController and connect it

   ```
   @IBAction func clickMe(_ sender: UIButton) {
       print("you click me")
   }
   ```

   - and give some color of your button for checking and click on that

   hope it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the extra view. If you delete this you can add a background colour to a normal button and change the background size and text size to make it appear the same.

If this isn't working you could go into your app design tool and make a coloured box and add this as an image into your button background.

After your button is set up you can add the @IBAction like any other normal button.

Hope it works, Toby